# Assets Control Panel searches only current folder, not sub folders?

Tags: assets, control-panel

When searching for an Asset in the Assets Control Panel, does it search everywhere? Does it search in subfolders? e.g., If I search for the title "image_1", does my search need to be done on the folder "image_1" is in for the search to return anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct... currently searching in Assets does not search across sub-folders.

Comment: Thanks. File under "Feature Requests"?

Comment: We would love for this feature to be included!